# 2 Routers One Modem

Tags: wireless-networking

My daughter has a PC + IPS modem + a good router.
I moved recently in her appartment, I have a MAC + a Time Machine/Airport; I am using her network, with her blessing, in order to save. 
Apple tells me I should connect my Airport to the modem so it can back-up regularly my data. My wireless Airport network will be used **only** to back-up MAC's data.
How should I connect my Airport to her modem that has only one ethernet connection that is used by her router. Also her IPS provides only one IP address. Can I use a simple ethernet splitter: to split her modem's connection 1-to her router, 2-to my Airport. Would this work without affecting her network.
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What are the make / model numbers of the devices?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can install a small switch between the modem and multiple devices, like 2 routers in your case, but because you specifically stated in your question:

> How should I connect my Airport to her modem that has only one
>   ethernet connection that is used by her router. Also her IPS provides
>   *only one IP address*.

Then this will not work. One can assume from that information that the ISP only allows one device (one MAC address) to be connected to the network at one time. Connecting a switch (ie. "ethernet splitter" as you called it) would result in only one of the devices working, or neither will work. The ISP may even detect an invalid configuration with multiple MAC addresses requesting service and temporarily suspend the connection entirely until the situation is rectified.

The solution would be to contact the ISP and request 2 IP addresses, which would likely be public, static IP addresses and would incur an additional monthly charge and possibly a setup fee. This would then require you and your daughter to manually configure the IP address information in your routers as well as connect a small switch to split the connection.

I am not familiar with Apple's Airport devices though, so there maybe some way to configure it to work behind her existing router.